# Android background service vs foreground service, which one is more battery efficient?

Tags: android, background, battery, foreground

I'm making an app and want to be battery efficient. I know that making the service as foreground is going to be less likely to be killed, but which one is more efficient in battery life? background or foreground?

Thank you in advance

Comment: They should be equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to target Android O and your service needs to run while your App is in the background, you have to use a foreground service anyway. If you only want it to run while your own app is in the foreground, just use a normal background service.

Alternatively depending on what you want to achieve you should take a look into JobScheduler.

In the end, I would not worry about the battery efficiency of background vs foreground service but make it dependent on what you need the service for.